Dice Sum Game- get close to 8; explicit calculation
I saw this question together with a nice answer:
Dice Sum Game
Here is the problem written out again:

You roll an eight sided dice, and keep track of the cumulative sum. You can stop and take the sum at any time, but if the sum is ever greater than 8 then the game ends, and you get a payout of zero. What is the expected value of this game? What is the best strategy?

Now the provided answer argues that if the current sum is less than or equal to 4 then we have a chance of 50% or more to get something below 8 if we roll again, so we should.
I was wondering wether this could be modeled and calculated explicitly. Let’s denote by $\{X_i\}_i$ the i.i.d. random variables describing the outcome of the i‘th roll and by $S_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ the current sum (I took probability last year and I think this would be called a supermartingale). Now we consider the stopping time $T_k=\inf \{n \geq 0 \ | \ S_n \geq k\}$ and get the stopped process $\{S_{n \wedge T_k}\}_n$ its limit is just $S_{T_k}$. Now we need to add the condition that we loose the money if our sum is greater than $8$. So our winnings are $S_{T_k} \chi_{S_{T_k} \leq 8}$. I now want to calculate its expected value and maximize it in $k$:
$$
\mathbb{E}[S_{T_k} \chi_{S_{T_k} \leq 8}]=\sum_{i=1}^{T_k}\mathbb{E}[X_i \chi_{S_{T_k} \leq 8}]
$$
But now I‘m not sure how to continue, so I quickly wanted to ask for help and wether my approach even works. Thank you:)

Fix $k$ and analyze the strategy "quit if you have $k$ or more but otherwise, roll again".  Pick the $k$ with the greatest expected value.

Yes, I know, this is essentially the strategy suggested in the answer. But I‘m interested in modeling it as a supermartingale to become more comfortable with them.

Given that there are only finitely many possible paths, I don''t think the extra machinery adds anything to the computation.  That is to say, everything reduces to the simple enumeration.  The machinery comes into play if, say, you are drawing a real number between $0$ and $1$ uniformly, say.
